# How to find longest accepted word by automata?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, automata, dfa

I need to write a code in Java that will find the longest word that DFA accepts. Firstly, if there is transition to one of previous states (or self-transition) on path that leads to final state, that means there are infinite words, and longest one doesn't exist (that means there is Kleene star applied on some word). I was thinking to form queue by BFS, where each level is separated by `null`, so that when I'm iterating through queue and come across `null`, length of the word would be increases by one, but it would be hard to track set of previous states so I'm kind of idealess. If you can't code in Java I would appreciate pseudocode or algorithm.

Comment: _"it would be hard to track set of previous states"_. Have you actually implemented this?

Comment: No. It's kind of pointless since it's BFS and I wouldn't know which path leads to final state.

Comment: If you also need to track the moves made, why haven't you tried a recursive DFS?

Comment: There could be multiple ways to get to the final state for longest word, which would require DFS to run multiple times from initial state. That's confusing.

Comment: How would you solve the problem by hand? (Hint: try to think in terms of longest acceptable prefixes for what will ultimately match, at a given node of the machine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is strictly necessary, but it would not hurt the performance too terribly much in practice and might be sufficient for your needs. I would suggest, as a first pass, minimizing the DFA. This can be done in O(nlogn) in terms of the number of states, using e.g. Hopcroft. This is probably conceptually similiar to what Christian Sloper suggests in the comments regarding reversing the transitions to find unproductive states ; indeed, there is a minimization algorithm that does this as well, but you might be able to get away with just removing unproductive states and not minimizing here (though minimizing does make the reasoning a little easier).

Doing that is nice because it will remove all unproductive loops and combine them into a single dead state, if indeed there are any unproductive prefixes. It is easy to find the one dead state, if there is one, and remove it from the directed graph formed by the DFA's states and transitions. To do this, do either DFS or BFS and check each state to come to and see if (1) all transitions are self-loops and (2) the state is not accepting.

With the one dead state removed (if any) any loops or cycles we detect in the remaining directed graph imply there are infinitely many strings in the language, since by definition any remaining states have a path to acceptance.  If we find a loop or cycle, we know the language is infinite, and can respond accordingly.

If there are no loops or cycles remaining after removing the dead state from the minimal DFA, what remains is a tree rooted at the start state and whose leaves are accepting states (think about this for a moment and you will see it must be true). Therefore, the length of the longest string accepted is the length (in edges) of the longest path from the root to a leaf; so basically the height of the tree or something close to it (depending on how you define depth/height, whether edges or nodes). You can take any old algorithm for finding the depth and modify it so that in addition to returning the depth, it returns the string corresponding to the deepest subtree, so you can get the string without having to go back through the tree. Something like this:

```
GetLongestStringInTree(root)
 1. if root is null return ""
 2. result = ""
 3. maxlen = 0
 4. for each transition
 5.  child = transition.target
 6.  symbol = transition.symbol
 7.  str = GetLongestStringInTree(child)
 8.  if str.length > maxlen then
 9.     maxlen = str.length
10.     result = str
11.  return result
```

This could be pretty easily modified to find all words of maximum length by adding str to a collection if its length is equal to the max length so far, and emptying that collection when a new longer string is found, and returning the collection (and using the length of the first thing in the collection for checking). That can be left as an exercise; as written, this will just find some arbitrary longest string accepted by the DFA.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This problem becomes a lot simpler if you split it in two. (Sorry no java)

Step 1: Determine if there is a loop.
If there is a loop there exist an infinite long input.  Detecting a loop in a directed graph can be done with DFS.

Step 2 (no loop): You now have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and you can find the longest path using this algorithm:  [Longest path in Directed acyclic graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Comment: The loop has to be on the path that leads to final, because there could be self-transitioning state that can't reach final state. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could BFS from each loop to see if you can reach the final state.

Comment: @qu4lizz: Before you do anything, eliminate all states which don't have a path to a final state. One simple way to do that is to run a DFS backwards from each final state, marking each state which you find; then, unmarked states can be deleted. (As usual, when doing DFS, you don't need to follow marked states, and you can use the same marks. So this algorithm is also linear.)

Comment: It's directed graph, so I don't have way (except some inefficient) to run inverted DFS. I'm not quite sure how removing those states would help me.

Comment: You can just treat a A->B edge as a B->A edge when running it inverted.  It is not inefficient.